# Filling in a report checkbox using the value of a column in a table

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-reports

In access, I have a table `TIndividus` linked to SQL with a column `Tind_Sentinelle` with `Yes`, `No`, `NULL`.

In my report I need a checkbox based on this column: if the value is `Yes` the checkbox is checked, else is unchecked.

I have tried to put the name of my column in the data control source but it doesn't work. (I'm new using Access so it's a little bit hard for me.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that the field `Tind_Sentinelle` is a **text** field containing the literal strings `Yes`, `No` (or is null), and also assuming that your table `TIndividus` is the Record Source for your report, then you should be able to set the **Control Source** property of your checkbox to the following:

```
=[tind_sentinelle]="Yes"
```